# Android - Google say my code has an Intent Vulnerability?

Tags: android, security, android-intent, google-play

My App is on Google play store recently i have got an email with the below description

[image]

i am not using Implicit intent except opening a Google Maps application

```
Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("google.navigation:q="+part3+","+part4);
    Log.v("My Point", "" + gmmIntentUri.toString());
        Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
        if (mapIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivity(mapIntent);
        }
```

i am confused how should i carry on with this, searched alot tried the steps mentioned here  (see article https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/9267555) but did not worked